# Is it possible to have databinding generate non-nullable accessors for variables?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am updating an app that uses the databinding library. I've been going through the breaking changes one by one, and I'm currently stuck on trying to access the binding variables. It looks like the accessors are now annotated with `@Nullable`, which means I have to use safe calls or assert non-null (which makes the code pretty ugly). Is there another alternative? Is there some sort of databinding setting that lets me change the generated annotations to `@NonNull`?

Generated code:

```
public abstract void setVm(@Nullable GeneralSettingsViewModel vm);

@Nullable
public GeneralSettingsViewModel getVm() {
  return mVm;
}
```

Somewhere in code:

```
//now I have to do this
binding.vm?.observeOrientation()
                ?.subscribe()
                ?.addTo(subscriptions)
```

Comment: Unless they generated Kotlin and used `lateinit`, I don't know how they would do what you want. They don't have an instance of `GeneralSettingsViewModel` until  you call `setVm()`, and we aren't invoking constructors where we could guarantee that they have a value at the outset. Still, if there is no feature request for it, you might file for one.

Comment: why don't you offload it to another variable?
`val vm = binding.vm ?: return` AFAIK it is not a straight forward approach to generate non-null accessors

Comment: @CommonsWare The rationale behind it makes perfect sense. I'll have to try something like what HawkPriest suggests. Thanks guys.